# Change the status of Modal from external function

Tags: reactjs

- I have a LogIn.js file where I have created a Modal.
- Using Hooks I can make the Modal appear and disappear, withing the same file or function.
- If I have a button on a function in a different file. How can I still make it appear by using the onClick properties of the button?

I tried accessing the state of the Modal in a different .js file using the following:

```
<Button
        className="btn-round btn-white"
        color="default"
        outline
        size="lg"
        onClick={() => {
          LogIn().setModal(true);
        }}
      >
        Sign In
      </Button

>

function LogIn() {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [firstFocus, setFirstFocus] = useState(false);
  const [lastFocus, setLastFocus] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Modal
          isOpen={modal}
        >
          <div className="modal-header justify-content-center">
            <button
              className="close"
              type="button"
              onClick={() => setModal(false)}
            >
```

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Answer (score 0):

Take the state up. In functional component state is local to a component.
React prefers composition.
Working [codeSandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-bhabha-e4op9) for reference.

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Login from "./Login";
import { Button } from "reactstrap";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button
        className="btn-round btn-white"
        color="default"
        outline
        size="lg"
        onClick={() => {
          setModal(true);
        }}
      >
        Sign In
      </Button>
      <Login modal={modal} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Login.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody } from "reactstrap";

export default function Login({ modal }) {
  return (
    <Modal isOpen={modal}>
      <ModalHeader>Modal title</ModalHeader>
      <ModalBody>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.
      </ModalBody>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Thank you for this. If I had a another button on a NavBar.js or a Footer.js. Would I just simply use the  onClick={() => {
          setModal(true); to make the Modal visible. Or Is there something I need to do the share the state between multiple .js files?

Comment: No that would work, its just that these components should be at same hierarchy to access modal state being set by setModal function returned by useState hook.

Comment: function App() { // Since you used this over here, I am not able to access the setModal from any other .js besides in this file.
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />  // Specially if there was a button here. How am I able to access the setModal in here? Please advise.
      <Button
        className="btn-round btn-white"
        color="default"
        outline
        size="lg"
        onClick={() => {
          setModal(true);
        }}
      >
        Sign In
      </Button>

Comment: Create a wrapper function and call setModal from that function, expose that function and pass as prop to any component to be called.

Comment: I tried this, all I got was errors. Is it possible for you do a quick example for this. Example would help me to do this for all my other components.